# Float: center doesn't work?

Tags: css, css-float, tumblr

I'm doing my first Tumblr theme using a tutorial, I'm a total newbie at this.

```
.metadata a {
display: inline-block;
float: center;
margin-left: 2%;
}
```

I want the posts to be centered, but the only things that work are float: left and float: right

What should I do ?
Please explain clearly because as I said, I'm a total newbie, and I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: There's no such thing as `float: center`. If the tutorial says there is, it's wrong.

Comment: Also, if you're trying to center the "post", you need to use a different tag.  In this css, not only are you using an incorrect attribute assignment, but you're hooking it only to `<a>` tags (or links) within the `.metadata` class.

Answer (score 8):

You can only float left or right, so float is not an option here.

Add `text-align: center` to the parent element of the a-tag. That will center not only text, but also other inline and inline-block elements, like yours.

Another way to center element, is to give them `display: block; margin 0 auto`. The 'automatic' left and right margins cause the element to be centered. It's a common trick to center elements, but it works on block elements only (or elements with `display: block`). That also means that you have to specify a width, because if you don't, the block element will consume 100% of the parent width.

I think in your case, an explicit width isn't an option, so text-align will be the best option.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but there is no `float: center;`. Use `margin: 0 auto;` to center block level elements and `text-align: center;` for inline.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "float" to control the orientation of your text, you'd likely want to use "text-align" and apply it to the parent of your a tag.  "text-align: center;" will apply to all inline elements (like a) within a parent.
See  [text-align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp)
and  [float](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)
documentation/tutorials.

Answer (score -1):

use this in CSS to center text in div that is inside floated div

```
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
```