# Wrapper float:center isn't working

Tags: css, wrapper

The question has been answered here - [Float: center doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647745/float-center-doesnt-work)

---

The whole page seems to be floating on the left. What have I done wrong? Any help would be so appreciated.

```
/*============================================================
 Wrapper
============================================================*/

#wrap {
width: 940px;
margin: 0px 0px auto 100px;
text-align: left;
float: cetner;

}



/*============================================================
 Header
============================================================*/

#header {
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 940px;
}

#header.image h1 span {

display: none;
float: center; 
}

#header h1 {
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 35px;
float: left; 
}

#header h1 span {
padding: 0px 0px 20px 10px;
}


/*============================================================
 Main Content Area
============================================================*/
#main {
float: left;
width: 960px;
margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}



/* Content -------------------------------------------------*/

#main-content {
float: center;
width: 960px;
padding: 0px;
background: #fff;
}

* html #main-content {
 width: 960px;
 w\idth: 960px;
  }
```

Comment: html would be helpful and or a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Float: center doesn't work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647745/float-center-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing like `float:center` in CSS.

Please read:

- [You can't float center](http://www.codeitpretty.com/2012/05/you-cant-float-center.html)

and then

- [Faking `float: center` with Pseudo Elements](http://css-tricks.com/float-center/)

The only floats you can natively use are "left", "right", "none" and "inherit".